# how to convert persian number to english

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get date(shamsi date) and then convert the numbers to english for calculations.
I need convert 'now' to english number.

```
    function HTMLUI(){}
    
    //display year
    HTMLUI.prototype.displayYear = function(){
        //get max year
        const now = new Date().toLocaleDateString('fa-IR')
    
        console.log(now.slice(0, 4));
    
    }
```

Comment: If you have a `Date` object, then you can just retrieve its values using the various methods on the `Date` object. There is no need to convert between Persian and English.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
HTMLUI.prototype.displayYear = function(){

    const theYear = new Date().getUTCFullYear().toString();
    
    console.log( theYear );
    
}
```